# Metallic voice effect

Tags: voice

does anyone know what type of plugin, voice fx, or processing was done to achieve this sound?

it starts at 3:25 in this clip and only lasts about 20 seconds

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't hear any effect....

Comment: It's subtle, but if you compare that part with the rest of the song it's more noticeable

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a couple of different vocal takes on top of eachother, maybe with a bit of subtle phasing and/or a chorus.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a vocoder, because you asked about metallic voice(I can't play the video because of slow internet connection)